# git repository on cloud sharing service to serve as access point for different OS

Tags: cloud, git

I work from two different computers. One runs the default flavor of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the other macOS. I use git for version control.

Google Drive doesn't exist for Ubuntu and I don't like having to essentially 'collaborate' with myself between the two computers.

So my question is how can I set up a git version controlled repository on a cloud file storage system like Google Drive such that I can access the files from the IDEs I have on either computer (i.e. the files should sync locally to each system).

VPN and SSH are not an option.

I have seen that GNOME 3.16 is an option but that requires install a new OS and is not ideal.

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
```

results in an error due to unmet dependencies.

Comment: As this doesn't answer the question posed but it relevant it seems posting as a comment is appropriate. There are a few Google Drive open source efforts for Ubuntu, one of which: https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/install-google-drive-ocamlfuse-on-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18